# C++ File adding

Tags: android, mobile

Can anyone please tell me how to add a C++ file in to an android project? Is there any method to import classes other than java classes?

Comment: You should look into the NDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: you have to go trough JNI - java native interfacew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that, you can't really add a C++ file directly to a project, but you can compile it and load it into the code that runs in your process and interface to it using the JNI.  This is a way to interface native code to Java.  However, be aware that you can't really do that much with the JNI.  Getting access to standard Android things like UI, Intents, service connections, etc.., these are all somewhat more difficult to use in native code.  And you certainly can't take a UNIX app "off the shelf" and stick it on Android by using the JNI.  [this](http://code.google.com/p/awesomeguy/wiki/JNITutorial) is a fairly good looking tutorial on the JNI with Android.  However, like I said, using the JNI is *not* an excuse for learning java and the Android SDK.  The main reasons people use native code are for utility code (like crypto stuff) and performance (for example, quite a few Android games use the NDK)..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use android NDK. Just download it and refer from android official site.